# how to get filter the data table

Tags: asp.net, database, binding

i have   datatable  with   which  contains  all theses  columns

```
columns  as  ID, NAME,PATH
```

i am  binding the  datatable  to  ID, Name  in  dropdown  control. once the user  selects a value  of  "name"  in the  dropdown .  i'll get the  ID of  it  . basesd on that  then i need to get the  corresponding   path value  in a string

thank  you

Answer (score 1):

Filtering datatable

```
DataView dtView = dtbl.DefaultView;
dtView.RowFilter = "[ID] <> 'ddlValue'";
value = dtView[0]["yourColumnName"].ToString();
```

where 0 is the rowIndex.

Comment: now i am  able  to get the    filter  records  it  contains  1  row  with   3  columns  .  now  i need  to assign  these values  into string   what is  syntax   to  do it

Comment: simply         value = dtView[0]["yourColumnName"].ToString();